# Is there a way to have a delay window for a scheduled task in the task scheduler

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have a task that I have set up that will auto reboot at a certain time. However, I would like an option for my users to delay the task. I know there is no option for this in the task scheduler itself but is there a way to edit the xml file to include one?

Comment: There is a way to allow this with some logic that gives options as such and does the delay. Perhaps with a batch script using some innovative solutions with VB Script or PowerShell. It wouldn't be the actual Task Scheduler that does the delay though but the logic that executes the process or whatever just to be clear.

Comment: we have this solution (delay via vbs) implemented in our company. works great, only problem is it has to run with user rights (system tasks are invisible to users) so if you have very advanced users they can not only delay but prevent it (kill via taskmgr)

Comment: what's the existing trigger? Time or other event?